What do Trump supporters think of his Cabinet nominations?
Since last week, Donald Trump has been announcing his planned Cabinet member nominations. Many people, including a number of Republican politicians and commentators in conservative media (including Fox News) have expressed great surprise at the lack of qualifications of most of the nominations, and some of them seem antithetical to the positions. For example, he wants former Congressman Matt Gaetz as Attorney General, even though he has been under investigation for ethics violations, soliciting prostitution, and having sex with under-age girls. And Tulsi Gabbard, who would be his Director of National Intelligence, is very sympathetic towards Russia and Vladimir Putin.
Have there been any polls of Republican citizens, particular those who were supporting Trump during his campaign, regarding their opinions of these nominations? Do they view them favorably?

This is very opinion based as you will find some of his supporters are all for the picks, while others don't have a strong opinion either way, and others may be strongly opposed to some or all of them. It is also possible that people may be in different camps based on who it is and what position they are being nominated for.

@JoeW the opinion poll measures opinion, but the result of the poll is an objective fact.  This should be well established on this site by now.

That is still hard to answer as your question right now is overly broad as it is asking about every appointment and from what I am seeing it varies from appointment to appointment. Unless the opinion poll is verifying that they are only getting answers from Trump supporters this question is impossible to answer as to my knowledge that isn't part of a normal poll.

I disagree, this is asking about a wide variety of candidates and opinions on those candidates. Any polling would need to exclude all non Trump supporters as well as those who don't know anything about the various people that got appointed and I don't see how you can find a poll that does any of that. Not much value in a response from someone if they don't know anything about the person in question.

Actually, there does seem to be a poll, from Echelon Insights. And the sentiment is roughly even, despite being across voters, not just Republicans.  So expect Republican voters sentiment to be more positive.
Newsweek - Matt Gaetz Is by Far the Least Popular Trump Pick With American Voters
(but the rest aren't criticized all that much)

Polling from Echelon Insights, conducted November 14-18, asked 1,010 voters (note:  not just Republicans, who can be expected to be more supportive) what they think of Trump's nominees for his cabinet, who will now have to be confirmed by the Senate.


They include vaccine skeptic Robert F. Kennedy Jr. as health and human services secretary; billionaire and owner of X and Tesla Elon Musk as director of the newly created Department of Government Efficiency; and Florida Representative Matt Gaetz, who has been under investigation by the House Ethics Committee, as attorney general, among others.


Despite being controversial figures, the poll revealed that more voters support Kennedy Jr. and Musk than oppose them. For example, 42 percent said they strongly or somewhat support Kennedy Jr., while 38 percent strongly or somewhat oppose his nomination to the cabinet. For Musk, 44 percent of voters support him, while 40 percent oppose him.


Two of Trump's picks had more voters opposing them than supporting them. They included the nominee for secretary of defense, Pete Hegseth, who was supported by 24 percent of voters and opposed by 26 percent, and Gaetz, whose net opposition was in double digits, with 37 percent opposed compared to 26 percent supporting him.

BBC - Trump voters say cabinet picks 'scare pants off establishment'

But while the prospective appointees could face pushback in the Senate, they have received a largely positive reception so far from Republican voters contacted by the BBC.


Virtually all of them approved of his cabinet picks, hailing them as much-needed disruptors to what they see as a corrupt establishment.


An opinion poll this week by Echelon Insights found that all of Trump’s cabinet picks - apart from Gaetz - have a slight edge in net favourability from members of the American public who participated in the survey.


But voter reaction mirrors sentiments about Trump himself and not all Republicans approve of his selections.


Michele Allen, a self-described "Never Trumper" from Arizona, told the BBC she is “flabbergasted” by the line-up

It makes sense that a Never Trumper Republican would not think much of this lot, but Never Trumpers are likely to be a minority at this point.
Early days, early days.  And, as one comment noted under the Q, outside of the political junkies, many of these people's specifics won't be known to Joe and Jane Average until they are seen in action.  To quote said comment:

Think of it this way, how many people are supporting Trumps nominations just because Trump picked them? Using Matt Gaetz as an example if there was a poll done in Alaska of Trump supporters that showed he had 95%+ support but 60%+ of the people polled either had no idea who he was or what scandals he is facing does that data really matter? Outside of the couple of scandal ridden examples you use cabinet nominations generally get strong support from the persons party and supporters. – Joe W

Update:  far as Gaetz goes, he's out of the running now, due to opposition in the Senate, rather than the electorate at large.

What is the source of the last (seemingly incomplete) quotation?  I don't see it in either of the linked articles.

Gaetz is unpopular largely because the reporting about him is intensely one-sided. A very quick look at a search for him on Google news shows that all of the top 10 stories are lurid allegations about his sex life and alleged crimes.

@phoog: that's just quoting JoeW comment from under the Q. Looking at the numbers from the  1st quote though, the average cabinet pick seems to have a popularity roughly equal to Trump's, which is expected.

Not a problem with your answer but rather with Newsweek's article (or maybe with my reading?) : they claim that both Gaetz and Hegseth have "more voters opposing them than supporting them", but contradict themselves three paragraphs further by saying that "all of Trump’s cabinet picks - apart from Gaetz - have a slight edge in net favourability", implying that Hegseth would not be in negative territory. Both results are presented as coming from the same Echelon Insights' polls.

@264champagnebottlesonice Thanks for explaining. Italian Philosopher: I would recommend quoting the entire comment.  As it is now, stopping in mid sentence with only one fork of the "either - or" clause, is is just confusing.

@phoog Your wish is my command.

@Valorum That many of the news stories concerning Gaetz center on his alleged crimes indicate that they are one-sided? These "crimes" have been the subject of both DOJ and Congressional investigations so they could be legitimately discussed in the mainstream media.

@doneal24 - when a politician receives wall-to-wall coverage focusing on a single allegation, It cannot possibly help their profile, especially when he is not famous enough that the general public have heard anything else about him. Kavanaugh had the same problem.

Why shouldn't reports of multiple instances human trafficking and statutory rape dominate the coverage of someone caught doing it? Surely we can't just sweep such crimes under the rug just because they make a politician look bad?

A newer poll that looks at some of these individually:

Many Republicans do not have an opinion of Hegseth: About 4 in 10 say they don’t know enough about him. About one-third of Republicans approve of him as a pick, and 16% disapprove. Another 1 in 10 Republicans, roughly, are neutral and say they neither approve nor disapprove.
Gabbard is as unknown as Hegseth is, but Americans are a little less likely to disapprove of her nomination. [...] Approval is slightly higher among Republicans than Hegseth’s, though. About 4 in 10 Republicans approve of the choice, while very few disapprove and 16% have a neutral view. Similar to Americans overall, about 4 in 10 Republicans don’t know enough to say.

OTOH

Once a contender for the Democratic presidential primary, Kennedy has become something of a GOP darling, with a strong majority of Republicans approving of him joining the Trump administration. About 6 in 10 Republicans approve, and only about 1 in 10 disapprove. About 2 in 10 are neutral, and about 1 in 10 don’t know enough about him to say.

As for Rubio

Most Republicans, nearly 6 in 10, approve, making his selection nearly as popular with this group as Kennedy’s. Only about 1 in 10 Republicans disapprove, while 14% are neutral and about 2 in 10 don’t know enough to say.

Note that this AP-NORC poll also has figures for overall popularity of these nominees, but I've quoted you the most relevant bit in the frame of your question, i.e. among "Trump supporters", which Republicans are the closest proxy in that poll.

Good update.  I figure this will be the question that keeps on giving.  I think RFK may lose his luster if he acts strongly on child vaccines though.  Well, one would hope so, anyway.

I don't remember the exact numbers, but on tonight's PBS News Hour I thought they reported that less than half of Trump voters are confident in Trump's nominees. Maybe it depends on whether they're asked about them as a group or about specific nominees.
